# Do event Pokémon have EV points?

Tags: pokemon-series

Do [event Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Event_Pok%C3%A9mon) (e.g., [those listed at Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/events/2012.shtml)) start with any EV points (e.g., the ones that come at level 100)? Or they are like captured Pokémon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While an event Pokémon technically *could* come with EVs, I don't think any ever have.

Since you specified level 100, it sounds like you're concerned about them not being able to *gain* any EVs. If my hunch is correct, you don't need to worry about that in Gen V (their effort values are applied independently from experience). For older gens, you can check out the [Box Trick](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Box_trick) (and read that anyway if you're interested; there's a note at the bottom about how it works in Gen V).

Answer (score 3):

All event Pokémon do not start with any EVs. They will have random IVs and random natures, unless they are predetermined.

You get EV's by battling and they've (technically) never battled.